# Converting IntWritatble to int

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following code and I didn't understand why `get()` method has been used in the highlighted line. If I remove that `get()` method it throws me an error.

What I can take out from it is: `get()` method returns the int value of the IntWritable. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<IntWritable, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        sum += values.next().get(); //error when removing the get()    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. [RamPrasad G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37270640/2516301) is also correct (+1), but, just to make it clearer:

`sum` is int. `values` is an `Iterator` to `IntWritable` elements, so `values.next()` is an `IntWritable`. Now, `IntWritable`, a data type of hadoop, is not equivalent to the primitive type `int` of java, even if they are used for the same thing: to store integer values.

Thus, you cannot add an `IntWritable` to an `int` (which is what you do if you remove the `get()` method). They are not of the same type. You have to convert the `IntWritable` to an `int`, which is done by the `get()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for verifying it !!

Answer (score 3):

In order to handle the Objects in Hadoop way, Hadoop uses Writable classes.
For example, Hadoop uses Text instead of java's String. similarly, The [IntWritable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/IntWritable.html) class in Hadoop is similar to a java int, however, IntWritable implements interfaces like Comparable, [Writable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html) and [WritableComparable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html).

These interfaces are all necessary for MapReduce; the `Comparable` interface is used for comparing when the reducer sorts the keys, and `Writable` can write the result to the local disk. It does not use the java `Serializable` because java `Serializable` is too big or too heavy for hadoop, `Writable` can serializable the hadoop Object in a very light way.

Writable interface is described as

> A serializable object which implements a simple, efficient,
>   serialization protocol, based on `DataInput` and `DataOutput`

Your `values.next()` is IntWritable class you have to use `get()` method to get primitive type of it.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike`int` and `Integer` auto boxing/un-boxing, same does not work for `int` and `IntWritable`.

The source code  [IntWritable](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.19.1-hudson-2/org/apache/hadoop/io/IntWritable.java/?v=source) provides more details for you to understanding the concept better.

```
/** A WritableComparable for ints. */
public class IntWritable implements WritableComparable {
  private int value;

  public IntWritable() {}

  public IntWritable(int value) { set(value); }

  /** Set the value of this IntWritable. */
  public void set(int value) { this.value = value; }

  /** Return the value of this IntWritable. */
  public int get() { return value; }
```

`IntWritable` is constructed from the `int` and the only way to get back `int` is with usage of `get()` API

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer is useful, you can upvote.